# Is there a way to modify class state from a function pointer passed to a C API?

Tags: c++, c, class, callback, global-variables

I have a class that has some internal state. The class uses a C library called GLFW to deal with window managing and keyboard input.

The class looks something like this:

```
class Object {
public:
    Object(...);
    ...
private:
    int _member_variable; // Internal state
    GLFWwindow *_window;
    ...
}
```

### Background about GLFW

GLFW is a C library that deals with window handling and keyboard input. It uses callback functions to report when the user presses keys when a window is focused.

```
void key_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    printf("User pressed key #%d\n", key);
}
```

To bind a callback function to a window you use a function called `glfwSetKeyCallback`.

```
// This will bind the `key_callback` function to `window`.
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
```

### The Problem I am having

I would like to modify the internal state of my class from a key callback function without relying on state with `static` storage. I cannot have global state because I would like to be able to create multiple instances of `Object` and have them working independently of each other.

Assume that I in this case would like to increment `_member_variable` each time the user presses a key.

I would like to do something like this:

```
// Private method for dealing with key presses.
void Object::key_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
        ++_member_variable; // Increment the internal state
}

Object::Object(GLFWwindow *window, ...)
: _window(window), ...
{
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
}
```

But this does not work as `Object::key_callback` is a member function for `Object` and require the invisible `this` argument. `(Object::*)(GLFWwindow *, int, int, int, int)` cannot be converted to `(*)(GLFWwindow *, int, int, int, int)`.

### What I have tried

- It is not possible to pass a private member function the GLFW API. That is understandable considering that the member functions require the invisible `this` argument.
- I have also tried using a lambda to capture the state I want but that also did not work.

Is there a way to modify class state from a function passed to a C API without relying on global state? Like in this case incrementing `_member_variable` from the function passed to `glfwSetKeyCallback`?

Comment: The problem is precisely with the `this` argument, and the fact that c++ modifies the function name in order to allow function overloading, so I think it's very hard if possible at all to pass a c++ class member function as if it was a c callback. There are options of course, and AFAIK the new c++ standard makes it easier to do this kind of things, but I am no expert.

Comment: As long the c-api doesn't provide a way to pass user data (like `this`), it's almost impossible. You might maintain a static map of `GLFWwindow*` pointers as keys and pointers to your corresponding class instances. But that's not easy to maintain I'm afraid.

Comment: @elias If you answer this question, you will get plenty of answers:  ***When a key is pressed, how would/could you find the object for which the member function shall be called ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is specific to the GLFW library, and is not trying to answer the more general programming language question. However, you migh find this useful as it addresses the issue you are really trying to solve.

GLFW does support a way which allows passing user-specific data to the callback via a [user pointer which can be specified per window](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window.html#window_userptr).

Some way to use this would could be this

```
class Object {
public:
    Object(...);
    ...
private:
    static void keyboard_callback_glfw(GLFWwindow *win_glfw, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods); // raw GLFW callback
    int _member_variable; // Internal state
    GLFWwindow *_window;
    ...
protected:
    void onKeyPress(int key, int scancode, int action, int mode); // object-oriented callback that does the work
}

void Object::keyboard_callback_glfw(GLFWwindow *win, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
     Object *obj=static_cast<Object*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(win));
     // call the Objects onKey() handler
     obj->onKeyPress(key, scancode, action, mode);
}
```

This scheme works also nicely with inheritance, so you can basically wrap GLFW and all of its callbacks in some "Window" class and derive from it, overridingthe various `onEvent` handlers, without having to care about the C-API of GLFW any more. You just have to `glfwSetWindowUserPointer(_window, this);` after the window is created in (or assigned to) your object, before the GLFW callbacks are registered.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. This solution is the one supported by GLFW's API.

A typical C library allows you to pass an opaque pointer to user data when you register a callback. `glfwSetKeyCallback` does not.

Instead, in GLFW, you call `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` to set a user pointer field inside the `GLFWWindow`. Set it to `this` in your `Object` constructor or wherever the window is actually created. Then, add a static member function to your `Object` class. This function can be private. Pass it as the callback to `glfwSetKeyCallback`. When this callback is called, retrieve the user pointer from the `GLFWWindow` using `glfwGetWindowUserPointer`, cast it to `Object*`, and use it to dispatch the call to that object's non-static member functions or modify data members directly.

http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window.html#window_userptr

**EDIT**

To make this answer more complete, let me comment on your attempted methods of solving this.

> - It is not possible to pass a private member function the GLFW API. That is understandable considering that the member functions require the invisible this argument.
> - I have also tried using a lambda to capture the state I want but that also did not work.

It is indeed possible to pass a private *static* member function as I and @derhass described (almost simultaneously). I'm sure you meant a non-static member function, however. As you observed, you would need the `this` pointer to dispatch to the right object. It might seem like you can set the `this` pointer using `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` and then pass a [pointer to a private non-static member function](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members). This won't work, however. Pointers to member functions are often implemented as "fat" pointers with extra data besides just an address. For example, see this [discussion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx). If you manage to cast one to a normal pointer and pass it to the C library, you will get truncation in one way or another. Even if you could avoid truncation by the cast, which I don't think you can, the C library doesn't have enough storage for the fat pointer and won't be able to return it to you intact.

Likewise, the same is generally true of lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to the callback is a pointer to a `GLFWwindow`. You can use that to identify your C++ window object, e.g. via a `std::unordered_map` (which then needs to have or be referenced from static storage). Then just pass the call on to a suitable method.

Be aware of threading issues.

Also, it's a good idea to think up front about responsibility for window creation and window destruction. GUI windows are typically self-destroying, and most likely your C windowing API is that way too. I have more or less landed on the technique of initiating API-level self-destruction and let that cause destruction of the C++ object, and not opposite, as yielding least complex code, but no matter what you choose it's a good idea to really think about this up front, before committing to design choices.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but I don't see how you can accomplish what you are trying to do without *some* global state. What you *can* do is create a global variable that stores pointers to your `Object` instances, and then call their member functions whenever `key_callback` runs. That way, you at least contain the damage because you will have just one global variable, you then won't have to make every instance of `Object` a global variable.

Here's some code that demonstrates what I'm trying to say:

```
// the only global variable in the code:
std::list<Object *> registeredObjects;

// register your callback to a free function instead of a member function
void key_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    // however, make this function call the member function of your Objects
    for (Object *registeredObject : registeredObjects)
        registeredObject->key_callback(window, key, scancode, action, mods);
}

// call this function to make your Objects able to react to key presses
void registerKeyCallback(Object *objectToRegister)
{
    for (Object *obj : registeredObjects)
        if (obj == objectToRegister) // is the given object already registered?
            return; // yes, so don't register again
    registeredObjects.push_back(objectToRegister);
}
```

With this code in place, you can call the `registerKeyCallback` function passing in the address of an `Object` that you want to be able to react to key presses, then that `Object` will be able to change its own internal state whenever it reacts to a key press. If the `Object::key_callback` function is private, then you can make the `key_callback` function a friend of your class, like so:

```
class Object
{
    ...
    friend void key_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);
};
```

Then, the `key_callback` function will be able to invoke the private `Object::key_callback` function.